# How to conditional format Color Cell based on Triplicated Text values

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, vbscript

I'm trying to color format cells in an Excel 2013 worksheet. I'm particularly interested in highlighting cells with names values that occur more than 2 times (i.e. triplicate names) in the same column. But, I have to highlight only the third repeated cell and ones after it. I have tried many VBA scripts I found elsewhere, but as I not an Excel expert, I was not succesful until now. Anyone could help on this?

Please check this screenshot here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfXm0.jpg) of the spreadsheet which shows the formula I'm trying now after some suggestions.

Thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: conditional formatting generally doesn't require VBA, why not just looking to Excel conditional formatting functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without macro:

- Select your data you want to format
- go to home - conditional formatting - new rule
- select "use a formula to determine which cell to format"
- enter formula `=COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)>2`, of course you need to update cell references:

  - `$A$1` is the cell above your range
  - `A2` is the first (and active!!) cell of range to be formatted
- click "format" and select highlight format

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that this will color every repetition after the third one, just in case you don't want this.

Comment: That's fairly obvious from the picture, isn't it?  If OP wants *only* the third occurrence highlighted, he can replace ">2" in the formula with "=3".

Comment: First of all, Thank you guys for helping. But, the suggested formula '=COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)>2' is not working. Excel shows me an error message (something is missing or wrong with the formula). To avoid the error message I have used a semicolon instead of a colon in the function and now the error message is gone. The case here is that it still not highlighting the names (Please, check screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/zGEti). Will the COUNTIF function work for names or only numbers?

Comment: yes, depending on your regional settings you may need to use `;` instead of `,`. Please post a screenshot where formula is visible too. Please don't post it in a comment, but update your question. Yes, `COUNTIF` works with text too.